# adding SOAP header in SOAP envelope using XSLT

Tags: xslt

i have an incoming SOAP message where there were no SOAP header tag present i need to add SOAP header in that. I am using this XSLT for doing this but SOAP HEADER is not getting added.
XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:dp="http://www.datapower.com/extensions" 
 xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
 extension-element-prefixes="dp" 
 exclude-result-prefixes="dp"  >
  <xsl:variable name="uuid" select="dp:variable('var://context/txn/uuid')" />
 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template> 
<xsl:template match="soapenv:Header">
    <soapenv:Header> 
        <UUID><xsl:value-of select="$uuid"/></UUID>
    </soapenv:Header>   
</xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The incomig SOAP mesagge can have header tag or it might not have header tag

Input SOAP Message Without Header tag:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <hmhs-medical-acknowledgement id="4080186649" result="FAIL""/>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Input SOAP Message With Header tag:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Header/>    
       <soapenv:Body>
          <hmhs-medical-acknowledgement id="4080186649" result="FAIL""/>
       </soapenv:Body>
 </soapenv:Envelope>
```

Required Output SOAP Message:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Header>
<UUID>71A4B2FA029D412787B06E07685ED101</UUID>
</soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <hmhs-medical-acknowledgement id="4080186649" result="FAIL""/>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Can somebody help how to add the SOAP header in that.

Comment: Please post an example of the XML input and the expected output. -- **Hint:** if the input has no SOAP header, then your 2nd template will never be executed.

Comment: Hi Michael,
Input SOAP Message:
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <hmhs-medical-acknowledgement id="4080186649" result="FAIL""/>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>


Output SOAP Message:
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Header>
<UUID>71A4B2FA029D412787B06E07685ED101</UUID>
</soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <hmhs-medical-acknowledgement id="4080186649" result="FAIL""/>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>

Comment: Please don't post code in comments - edit your question instead.

Comment: Hi Michael,Sorry for this i have updated my question added the incoming SOAP message and the required output SOAP message.let me know how to get the required result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAICT, you want to do:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:dp="http://www.datapower.com/extensions" 
xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
extension-element-prefixes="dp">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:variable name="uuid" select="dp:variable('var://context/txn/uuid')" />

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/soapenv:Envelope">
    <xsl:copy>
        <soapenv:Header>
            <UUID><xsl:value-of select="$uuid"/></UUID>
        </soapenv:Header>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="soapenv:Header"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks Michael, This solution is working fine. I am having another issue is like some time i am getting a empty header tag like "<soapenv:Header>" . So in this scenario this is not working. If there were no "<soapenv:Header>" tag then this code is working. How can we put a conditonal check for "<soapenv:Header>: tag is present or not and based on that we can choose either fortemplate match="/soapenv:Envelope " or "template match="/soapenv:Header" can you help on this how we can write this.

Comment: Please edit your question and show an example of an input with the empty header.

Comment: Hi Michael, i have added two possible incoming SOAP message one is like With HEADER tag and other one is without HEADER tag in SOAP message.  consumer is sending some time HEADER tag and  sometime it is not coming .let me know how i can get the desired result

Comment: Hi Michael, Yes it's working fine. Thank you so much for your help. I will close it by accept this answer.